# Conditional sums based on lookups in a second table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table “Items” that's a bit like this:

```
+------+----------+-------+
| CODE |  STUFF   | HOURS |
+------+----------+-------+
|      |          |       |
| A    | Blah     | 40    |
|      |          |       |
| B    | Etc      | 10    |
|      |          |       |
| C    | Junk     | 20    |
|      |          |       |
| D    | Whocares | 10    |
+------+----------+-------+
```

Each code will appear once. The table is not sorted. I cannot modify this table or add new columns to it.

I need to categorise and group this information so I have another table “Categories” that I can edit like this:

```
+------+----------+
| CODE | CATEGORY |
+------+----------+
|      |          |
| A    | Red      |
|      |          |
| B    | Blue     |
|      |          |
| C    | Red      |
|      |          |
| D    | Blue     |
+------+----------+
```

I want to in effect create a pivot table that sums hour by category, i.e.

```
+----------+-------+
| CATEGORY | HOURS |
+----------+-------+
|          |       |
| Red      | 60    |
|          |       |
| Blue     | 20    |
+----------+-------+
```

If I could add a column with a `VLOOKUP` to the main table, I could then use a pivot table or some `SUMIF`s and all would be good. But I can't. So I've tried various increasingly creative uses of array formulae, `SUMPRODUCT`s and Google, but I am stuck.

Another way to describe it: if this was SQL I’d do:

```
SELECT Categories.Category, SUM(Items.Hours) FROM Items INNER JOIN Categories ON Items.Code = Categories.Code GROUP BY Categories.Category
```

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: put a `sumifs()` column in the second table AND a `sumifs()` column in the third table.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Create Input and Output table as per above picture

In I3, array (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) formula copied down :

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($C$3:$C$6,$A$3:$A$6,IF($F$3:$F$6=H3,$E$3:$E$6)))
```